# Is it possible to get all valid methods for a particular Perl class?

Tags: perl, class, oop, methods

Is it possible to get all valid methods for a particular Perl class?

I am trying to manipulate the symbol table of a class and get all of its methods. I found I can separate out the subroutines from the non-subroutines via the `$obj->can($method)`, but that doesn't do exactly what I think it does.

The following returns:

```
subroutine, Property, croak, Group, confess, carp, File
```

However, `subroutine` isn't a method, (just a subroutine), and `croak`, `confess`, and `carp` were all imported into my package.

What I really want to print out is:

```
Property,Group, File
```

But I'll take:

```
subroutine, Property,Group, File
```

Below is my program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $sections = Section_group->new;
say join ", ", $sections->Sections;

package Section_group;
use Carp;

sub new     {
    return bless {}, shift;
}

sub Add {
    my $self                = shift;
    my $section             = shift;
}

sub Sections {
    my $self                = shift;

    my @sections;
    for my $symbol ( keys %Section_group:: ) {
        next if $symbol eq "new";   # This is a constructor
        next if $symbol eq "Add";   # Not interested in this method
        next if $symbol eq "Sections";      # This is it's own method
        push @sections, $symbol if $self->can($symbol);
    }

    return wantarray ? @sections : \@sections;
}

sub subroutine {
    my $param1              = shift;
    my $param2              = shift;
}

sub Group {
    my $self                = shift;
    my $section             = shift;
}

sub File {
    my $self                = shift;
    my $section             = shift;
}

sub Property {
    my $self                = shift;
    my $section             = shift;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fairly trivial. We only want to keep those sub names that were originally defined in our package. Every CV (code value) has a pointer to the package where it was defined. Thanks to [`B`](https://metacpan.org/module/B), we can examine that:

```
use B ();

...

if (my $coderef = $self->can($symbol)) {
  my $cv = B::svref_2object $coderef;
  push @sections, $symbol if $cv->STASH->NAME eq __PACKAGE__;
}

# Output as wanted
```

That is, we perform introspection using `svref_2object`. This returns a Perl object representing an internal perl data structure.

If we look into a coderef, we get a [`B::CV` object](https://metacpan.org/module/B#B%3a%3aCV-Methods), which represents the internal [CV](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.42/index-14.html#cv). The `STASH` field in a CV points to the Stash where it was defined. As you know, a Stash is just a special hash (internally represented as a [HV](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.42/index-14.html#hv)), so `$cv->STASH` returns a [`B::HV`](https://metacpan.org/module/B#B%3a%3aHV-Methods). The `NAME` field of a `HV` contains the fully qualified package name of the Stash if the HV is a Stash, and not a regular hash.

Now we have all the info we need, and can compare the wanted package name to the name of the stash of the coderef.

Of course, this is simplified, and you will want to recurse through `@ISA` for general classes.

---

Nobody likes polluted namespaces. Thankfully, there are modules that remove foreign symbols from the Stash, e.g. `namespace::clean`. This is no problem when the CVs of all subs you are calling are known at compile time.

Comment: Then again, sometimes people actually do import a method from another package (e.g. `use Exporter 'import';` as opposed to `@ISA = qw(Exporter);`).

Comment: @cjm Of course, but I'd guess this doesn't happen to often, and may even be an antipattern. Hopefully, most people have mentally seperated procedural programming (with imports) from OOP (which solves many namespace problems). There is no way to know if an imported sub was meant to be a method, so this will have to be good enough. (Wait, maybe if we can access the `:method` attribute…)

Comment: _This is fairly trivial_. Trivial? You build tachyon generators on the weekends? Perldoc on **svref_2object**: _Takes a reference to any Perl value, and turns the referred-to value into an object in the appropriate B::OP-derived or B::SV-derived class._ I have no idea what it's talking about. However, it does work. I guess it's time for me to delve into the previously undelved and improve my Perl game a bit more. Either that, or learn Python.

Comment: @DavidW. Yes, the `B` documentation is absymal. The target audience is people who are already familiar with the basics of the Perl Core. I expanded the explanation with links to the `illguts`, which is named so because it is illustrated (with loads of enlightening pointer diagrams), and covers the topic of the `perlguts` manpage. Why yes, I did learn that for a weekend project, although I was just trying to write a Hello World using B::Generate (create perl opcodes in Perl). The “trivial” only meant we didn't have to write any C code: there is a module for that.

Comment: @amon Thanks for the links. I got concerned when illguts stated that Perl internals were refactored twice since 5.10. I tested your solution on 5.12, but the server is using 5.8.8. However, your solution still works on 5.8.8. I'm a CM and haven't done serious development in years. I use to know 8085A assembler and was pretty good with C on Xenix which I guess dates me a bit. I'll go through illguts and see how much my brain can hold. There's a lot of stuff in their from the 1980s, but I'll find room.

Answer (score 6):

What are you trying to do? Why does it matter how a class defined or implements a method it responds to?

Perl is a dynamic language, so that means that methods don't have to exist at all. With `AUTOLOAD`, a method might be perfectly fine and callable, but never show up in the symbol table. A good interface would make `can` work in those cases, but there might be cases where a class or an object decides to respond to that with false.

The [Package::Stash](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Package%3a%3aStash) module can help you find defined subroutines in a particular namespace, but as you say, they might not be defined in the same file. The methods in a class might come from an inherited class. If you care about where they come from, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I have a class called _Sections_ which represents various section types in my control file which is in Windows INI format. Each section has parameters, but the parameters are different for each type of Section. (There are currently five of them). Each type of section is a subclass of Section. I have another class that holds all the various section list for me. Each section type gets a new method in that last class. This way, my whole definition for that INI file is in a single object. One method on my class gets me the names of all the other subclasses.

Comment: I used to use AUTOLOAD but I now avoid it. Using `use strict` makes programming better. Using reference structures removes that safety. I may have `$foo->{BAR}` in one place and `$foo->{BRA}` in another, and strict cant' catch that. OO puts back that safety. If my method is $foo->Bar, calling $foo->Bra will crash my program. AUTOLOAD breaks that design. Both are now real methods. It also lends to poorer overall design. I can wing it with AUTOLOAD. I don't have to think things through. My prev version of this program used AUTOLOAD, and it can be hard to debug thanks to AUTOLOAD.

Comment: I'd add all that explanation to the question :)